# Grunt: How can I change file mode bits (chmod)?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I like to generate a shell script inside the grunt build file and set the execution bit.

In my task i do the following:

```
grunt.registerTask('createScript', 'Creates the script', function() {
    var ejs = require('ejs');
    //...
    grunt.file.write(
        './build/myScript.sh',
        ejs.render( grunt.file.read('myScript.sh.ejs'), { locals:myParams } )
    );
});
```

It seems that neither `grunt.file.write` nor `grunt.file` have an option to specify the file mode bits. (see [API grunt.file](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/grunt.file))

How can I set the bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because grunt runs in node, we can simply use the file system module `fs` of node. `fs` has a method `chmod()` / `chmodSync()`.

The code example could than look like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('createScript', 'Creates the script', function() {
    var ejs = require('ejs');
    var fs = require('fs');
    //...
    grunt.file.write(
        './build/myScript.sh',
        ejs.render( grunt.file.read('myScript.sh.ejs'), { locals:myParams } )
    );
    fs.chmodSync('./build/myScript.sh', '777');
});
```